# Постоянное соединение с базой MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Из-за повторных соединений с базой возникает существенная нагрузка на сервер *MySQL*, на эти операции приходится 64% от общей нагрузки, неизбежно приходиться смотреть в сторону постоянного подключения, подскажите как лучше это сделать? *PDO* или *Myqli*? Сейчас сайт сверстан на *PDO*. Читал в интернете, что при постоянном соединений не рекомендуется *PDO*. С радостью приму также дополнительные советы.

Вот статистика нагрузки на базу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: больше данных надо, какова посещаемость сайта, что значит повторные соединения?

Comment: Как измеряли 64% нагрузки? И это 64% от чего? CPU, времени по данным профилировщика, ещё чего-нибудь? Просто mysql архитектурно умеет легко открывать-закрывать коннекты и то как выглядит ваш вопрос - не указаны абсолютно никакие детали - не очень похоже, что у вас десятки тысяч rps.

Comment: На сайте в среднем 700 посетителей. В статистике по базе написано: Суммарное время подключений - 350 сек. Суммарное время обработки запросов - 193 сек. Вот и выходит 65%

Comment: Где именно это написано? Вы уверены, что это время затраченное на протокол установки подключения, а не, например, суммарное время жизни коннектов?

Comment: В вопросе добавил скриншот со статистикой

Comment: Ваш скриншот совершенно не ответил на мой вопрос. Что именно показывает эта циферка?

Comment: Одно, впрочем, на этой картинке заметить можно: у вас подключений даже больше чем число запросов. Соответственно вы их устанавливаете без всякой в том необходимости.

Comment: 3-6 минут загрузки в сутки считается какой то нагрузкой что ли? а что у вас там происходит то, что по 100к апдейтов/инсертов делается день?

Comment: Наверно Вы правы, скорее всего это суммарное время жизни подключений, я еще уточню у хостинга.

Comment: teran - сам не знаю откуда столько запросов, попытаюсь выяснить

Comment: полагаю, никто из посетителей не будет ждать 180 секунд и закроет сайт. Откуда этот скриншот, как называется прога?

Comment: А может дело не в повторном соединении? а в плохих скриптах `MYSQL` ? И еще кода заканчивается скрипт `MYSQL` вы уверены что закрываете соединение? Я работал над очень большим сайтом форекс, и там таких проблем некогда не возникало.

Comment: Хм, у вас там случайно не на каждый запрос к базу подключение создаётся? Если при одном запросе юзера у вас 2 инсерта, к примеру, то должно всего 1 соединение создаваться. У вас же получается явно больше 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала, [ссылка](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo), просто прочитайте всё там - минут 10, зато многие вопросы сами собой отпадут.

1. Не понимаю, откуда взялась эта дурацкая легенда о том, что нужно обязательно "закрывать" соединение? Может так и было в php версии 4 и ниже, на устаревшем ныне расширении mysql, но в PDO совершенно точно это не так. Вот просто реально, все кто про это пишет - зайдите и еще раз внимательно [прочитайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php).

> При успешном подключении к базе данных в скрипт будет возвращен
>   созданный PDO объект. Соединение остается активным на протяжении всего
>   времени жизни объекта. Чтобы закрыть соединение, необходимо уничтожить
>   объект путем удаления всех ссылок на него (этого можно добиться,
>   присваивая NULL всем переменным, указывающим на объект). Если не
>   сделать этого явно, PHP автоматически закроет соединение по окончании
>   работы скрипта.

2. Как правильно пишут товарищи в комментариях - по-хорошему, за выполнение скрипта соединение должно создаваться один лишь раз. Как вы это реализуете - без разницы: можно использовать глобальную переменную, можно использовать статическую переменную функции, можно использовать статический метод класса (со статической переменной класса). Все кто пишут просто "статические методы - плохо", это, конечно, гениально, повторять за большинством, но я реально не вижу ни одной разумной причины, по которой, например, для каждого объекта люди почему-то создают новое соединение. И уж совершенно точно не нужно на каждый запрос открывать отдельное соединение.
3. Раз уж у вас есть PDO - используйте его возможности на максимум:

   а. используйте подготовленные запросы и никогда не вклеивайте переменные вручную в строку запроса.

   б. где нужно именно выполнить несколько запросов в цикле - делаете PDO::prepare перед циклом, записываете в переменную, далее в цикле уже выполняете PDOStatement::execute и PDOStatement::fetchAll. Но всё же в большинстве случаев рекомендую подумать - а нельзя ли все необходимые данные вытянуть, всё же, одним запросом.

   в. ознакомьтесь с константами PDO::FETCH_*. чаще всего необходимы:

   - PDO::FETCH_ASSOC - почти всегда (рекомендуется его вообще прописать в опциях соединения, как режим извлечения по-умолчанию)
   - PDO::FETCH_COLUMN - когда нужно получить массив, в котором собраны все значения лишь по одному из столбцов в бд
   - PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR - ключ - первое поле выборки, значение - второе поле выборки (например массив [ id_клиента => имя_клиента ]).
   - PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC - когда нужно получить массив, ключом которого станет первое поле из выборки, а значением - массив данных.
   - PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC - вообще чудеснейшая комбинация, по первому полю выборка группируется и раскладывается на отдельные "подмассивы".

P.S. ну и, не относится напрямую к PDO, не забывайте про ключи и предподготовку статистических данных (судя по тому, что у Вас всего три апдейта за сутки - это должно сократить время выборок в разы).